# Почему значение scipy.norm.pdf (функция плотности вероятности) может быть больше единицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, numpy, scipy

Подскажите пожалуйста:
есть ряд y ~ I(1), т.е. интегрирован первого порядка (нестационарен). Для приведения к стационарности использую прирост логарифма. Проблема в том, что когда вывожу график функции плотности, по oY, там где должны быть вероятности в десятичной форме получаются значения больше единицы. С ядерной оценкой тоже самое. Преподаватель хочет именно прирост логарифма.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sts

np.random.seed(123)
y = np.linspace(50,200,150) + np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=15, size=150)
x = np.diff(np.log(y))
mu, sigma = sts.norm.fit(x)
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
x_l = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(x))
dens = sts.norm.pdf(x_l, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
plt.plot(x_l, dens)

dens_kde = sts.gaussian_kde(x)
dens_pdf = dens_kde.evaluate(x_l)
plt.plot(x_l, dens_pdf)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38142058/5741205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sts.norm.pdf` функция плотности вероятности (Probability density function) может возвращать значения больше единицы, но если ее проинтегрировать должно получиться значение близкое к единице:

```
In [152]: from scipy.integrate import simps

In [153]: simps(dens, x=x_l)
Out[153]: 0.999763132933244
```

[Подробнее об этом можно прочитать в данном вопросе/ответе в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141951/why-does-scipy-norm-pdf-sometimes-give-pdf-1-how-to-correct-it)

Comment: спасибо большое, попробовал - работает. Единственное смущает вывод значений больше единицы на графике, но если интеграл равен единице (почти) это хорошо, просто если спросят почему так, боюсь что не смогу ответить

Comment: Почитал пост, который Вы предоставили, теперь все стало на свои места, благодарю.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, может есть готовая функция по нахождению несобственного интеграла, а именно с границами  -inf/+inf. Хотелось бы вычислить математическое ожидание непрерывной случайной величины.

Comment: @St.Vladislav, [не оно?](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect.html)

Comment: Вообще похоже, но как я понял нижняя и верхняя границы задаются скаляром, а не бесконечностью, в итоге получается что вычисляется ожидаемое значение на интервале определяемом границами lb ub соответственно. Однако традиционно математическое ожидание рассчитывается как интеграл с границами от -inf до +inf, а подынтегральная функция это произведение xi на f(x) по dx. Данная функция, исходя из документации не поддерживает такие границы, надо попробовать поставить lb=ub=None и сравнить с решением на "бумаге".

Comment: Благодарю Вас за содействие, ибо данный язык программирования я изучаю относительно недавно

Comment: @St.Vladislav значения больше единицы для pdf не имеет никакого отношения к Питону. К примеру, для величины принимающей фиксированное значение pdf будет дельта-функцией (бесконечность). Для любого распределения интеграл pdf по всему пространству всегда равен единице. Это из определения следует.

Comment: Это понятно, просто смутили значения плотности больше единицы, но я уже разобрался. Да, интеграл от -inf/+inf для функции плотности равен единице, убедился с помощью метода integrate_box, класса scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde, это из определения. Сейчас пытаюсь найти математическое ожидание: интеграл от -inf до +inf x*f(x)dx, подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать, на примере вышеуказанного кода

Comment: вот что я придумал, касательно вопроса из предыдущего комментария: если x - числовой ряд, тогда fx = sts.gaussian_kde(x); def f(x): return x*fx(x); таким образом получается f(x) подынтегральная функция, нахождения математического ожидания, необходимо взять интеграл от -inf/+inf данной функции. Для этого я воспользовался from scipy.integrate import  quad. Далее нашел интеграл: quad(f, -np.inf, np.inf). Прошу прощения за не самый презентабельный вид кода.